# Database multiple data not show in html file - django 2.1

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i making a web page to get data from database and show in web page.i used **.get()** and it only get one data from database. and a tried **.all()** with many  times. but can't show any data in html file. **i need to get multiple data from database and show in web page**

here my code

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import data

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def postjob(request):

    data.objects.all()
    context = {
        "title": data.title,
        "jobType": data.jobType,
        "des": data.description,
        "jImg": data.jImg
        }

    return render(request, 'jobpost.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class data(models.Model):
   title = models.TextField()
   jobType = models.TextField()
   description = models.TextField()
   jImg = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from diligent.views import index, about, postjob
from webDiligent import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('', index, name='index'),
     path('about/', about, name='about'),
     path('jobpost/', postjob, name='postjob'),
 ]



urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**jobpost.html**

```
<div class="row">
                {% for con in context %}

                <!-- single product -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-product">

                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{con.jImg.url}}" alt="">

                        <div class="product-details">
                            <h5>{{con.title}}</h5>
                            <div class="price">
                                <h6>{{con.jobType}}</h6>
                                <p>{{con.description}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="prd-bottom"><a href="submitcv.html">Send Your CV</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your view like this:

you have to pass all the objects through dictionary in your template:

```
def postjob(request):

        datas = data.objects.all()
        context = {
            'datas':datas
            }

        return render(request, 'jobpost.html', context)
```

in template:

```
 {% for data in datas %}

                <!-- single product -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-product">

                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{data.jImg.url}}" alt="">

                        <div class="product-details">
                            <h5>{{data.title}}</h5>
                            <div class="price">
                                <h6>{{data.jobType}}</h6>
                                <p>{{data.description}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="prd-bottom"><a href="submitcv.html">Send Your CV</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```